# Safe to use // over https:// or http://

Tags: html, css

On our website we have some secure and unsecure pages. Should we always link images, css etc using the full https:// or how safe is it to link everything using // ?

```
Example 1:
<link href="https://www.domain.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Example 2:
<link href="//www.domain.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure all traffic is encrypted, use https just to be safe. It can't hurt; it can only make your traffic more secure.